# Scraping Google images with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-2.x

I'm trying to learn Python scraping and came across a program to scrape a set number of images from Google image search results

I changed it to go for 5 images, it was working for a while but it stopped working recently with showing outputs such as `there are 0 images`

```
import requests
import re
import urllib2
import os
import cookielib
import json

def get_soup(url,header):
    return BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(urllib2.Request(url,headers=header)),'html.parser')


query = raw_input("query image")# you can change the query for the image  here
image_type="ActiOn"
query= query.split()
query='+'.join(query)
url="https://www.google.com/search?q="+query+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
print url
#add the directory for your image here
DIR="C:\Users\mynam\Desktop\WB"
header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"
}
soup = get_soup(url,header)


ActualImages=[]# contains the link for Large original images, type of  image
for a in soup.find_all("div",{"class":"rg_meta"}):
    link , Type =json.loads(a.text)["ou"]  ,json.loads(a.text)["ity"]
    ActualImages.append((link,Type))

print  "there are total" , len(ActualImages),"images"

if not os.path.exists(DIR):
            os.mkdir(DIR)
DIR = os.path.join(DIR, query.split()[0])

if not os.path.exists(DIR):
            os.mkdir(DIR)
###print images
for i , (img , Type) in enumerate(ActualImages[0:5]):
    try:
        req = urllib2.Request(img, headers={'User-Agent' : header})
        raw_img = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()

        cntr = len([i for i in os.listdir(DIR) if image_type in i]) + 1
        print cntr
        if len(Type)==0:
            f = open(os.path.join(DIR , image_type + "_"+ str(cntr)+".jpg"), 'wb')
        else :
            f = open(os.path.join(DIR , image_type + "_"+ str(cntr)+"."+Type), 'wb')


        f.write(raw_img)
        f.close()
    except Exception as e:
        print "could not load : "+img
        print e
```

There are no error logs, the file gets created and it is empty. The `ActualImages` array remains empty for some reason.

Comment: Maybe you've got captcha from google?

Answer (score 8):

it seems that Google has **recently** removed the metadata from the image search result, i.e. you won't find `rg_meta` in the HTML. Therefore, `soup.find_all("div",{"class":"rg_meta"}):` will not return anything.

I haven't found a solution for this. I believe Google made this change for the very purpose of preventing **scraping**.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't seen anyone mention this. Not an ideal solution but if you want something simple that works and doesn't take any hassle to setup you can use selenium. Since google seems to intentionally be preventing image scraping as Densus mentioned perhaps this would be inappropriate usage of selenium, I'm not sure.

There's plenty of public, working selenium google image scrapers on github that you can view and use. In fact, if you search for any recent python google image scraper on github I think most if not all of them will be selenium implementations.

For example:
https://github.com/Msalmannasir/Google_image_scraper

This one, just download the chromium driver and update the filepath to it in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same problem, cant find rg_meta
I found a code which can download approximately first 80 images though.. but does not work for scrolling

```
extensions = { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif" }

html = browser.page_source.split('["')
print(html)
imges = []
for i in html:
    if i.startswith('http') and i.split('"')[0].split('.')[-1] in extensions:
        x=i.split('"')[0]


        if(succounter>=totalcount):
            break
        counter = counter + 1
        print "Total Count:", counter
        print "Succsessful Count:", succounter
        print "URL:",x

        try:
            req = urllib2.Request(x, headers={'User-Agent': header})
            succounter = succounter + 1
            if(succounter>1000):
                break
        except:
                print "can't get img"
```

Comment: For scrolling on Google Images browser sends XHR with additional parameters. Check it in dev tools and send request from Python to the same URL.

Answer (score 0):

Two problems in code you've provided:

- Google injects part of `rg_meta` tags via `_defd` JS function. You need to extract and decode it's arguments
- Google Images also contain images directly as HTML tags instead of `.rg_meta`. You can parse them as usual HTML tags.

Part of Google's JS code from Google Images that injects tags. The first argument `defd1` is an ID of the placeholder HTML element to be replaced with contents. The second argument is the encoded HTML string.

```js
_defd('defd1','\x3cdiv  jsaction\x3d\x22IE7JUb:e5gl8b;MW7oTe:fL5Ibf;dtRDof:s370ud;R3mad:ZCNXMe;v03O1c:cJhY7b;\x22 data-ved\x3d\x222ahUKEwiGmK7a3szoAhVDB3cKHesrAQoQMygVegQIARBY\x22  data-ictx\x3d\x221\x22 data-id\x3d\x229pyRez7A01yLeM\x22 jsname\x3d\x22N9Xkfe\x22 data-ri\x3d\x2221\x22 class\x3d\x22isv-r PNCib MSM1fd BUooTd\x22 jscontroller\x3d\x22SI4J6c\x22 jsmodel\x3d\x22uZbpBf sB4qxc\x22 jsdata\x3d\x22j0Opre;9pyRez7A01yLeM;27\x22 style\x3d\x22width:283px;\x22 data-tbnid\x3d\x229pyRez7A01yLeM\x22  data-ct\x3d\x220\x22 data-cb\x3d\x220\x22 data-cl\x3d\x220\x22 data-cr\x3d\x223\x22 data-tw\x3d\x22299\x22 data-ow\x3d\x221100\x22 data-oh\x3d\x22619\x22\x3e\x3ca class\x3d\x22wXeWr islib nfEiy mM5pbd\x22 jsname\x3d\x22sTFXNd\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22click:J9iaEb;\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22mousedown:npT2md; touchstart:npT2md;\x22 data-nav\x3d\x221\x22 tabindex\x3d\x220\x22 style\x3d\x22height:164px;\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22bRMDJf islir\x22 jsname\x3d\x22DeysSe\x22 style\x3d\x22background:rgb(200,194,187);width:292px; height:164px;margin-left:0px; margin-right:-9px;\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22mousedown:npT2md; touchstart:npT2md;\x22\x3e\x3cimg class\x3d\x22rg_i Q4LuWd tx8vtf\x22 data-src\x3d\x22https:\/\/encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com\/images?q\x3dtbn%3AANd9GcQ3_h7vxb_72egN52iUj6J4TQs7XajUVhI6BxP_tMepqnFdcGL1\x26amp;usqp\x3dCAU\x22 data-lt\x3d\x22\x22  jsname\x3d\x22Q4LuWd\x22  alt\x3d\x22Jamaican Coffee Companies Devise Plan to Court US Market - OECS ...\x22 \/\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22c7cjWc\x22\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22PiLIec\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22click: gFs2Re\x22\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e\x3c\/a\x3e\x3ca class\x3d\x22VFACy kGQAp\x22 data-ved\x3d\x222ahUKEwiGmK7a3szoAhVDB3cKHesrAQoQr4kDegQIARBZ\x22 jsname\x3d\x22uy6ald\x22 rel\x3d\x22noopener\x22 target\x3d\x22_blank\x22 href\x3d\x22http:\/\/oecsbusinessfocus.com\/jamaican-coffee-companies-devise-plan-to-court-us-market\/\x22 jsaction\x3d\x22focus:kvVbVb; mousedown:kvVbVb; touchstart:kvVbVb;\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22sMi44c lNHeqe\x22\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22WGvvNb\x22 \x3eJamaican Coffee Companies Devise Plan ...\x3c\/div\x3e\x3cdiv class\x3d\x22fxgdke\x22\x3eoecsbusinessfocus.com\x3c\/div\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e\x3c\/a\x3e\x3c\/div\x3e')
```

---

Alternatively, you can use [`google-search-results`](https://pypi.org/project/google-search-results) package to extract data from Google Images.

[Full example at Repl.it](https://repl.it/@ilyazub/LustrousExtrovertedDistributionsoftware)

```py
from serpapi import GoogleSearch
import os

params = {
    "engine": "google",
    "q": "coffee",
    "tbm": "isch",
    "api_key": os.getenv("API_KEY"),
}

client = GoogleSearch(params)
data = client.get_dict()

print(f"Raw HTML: {data['search_metadata']['raw_html_file']}")
print(f"JSON endpoint: {data['search_metadata']['json_endpoint']}")
print()

print("Images results")

for result in data['images_results']:
    print(f"""
Title: {result['title']}
Source: {result['source']}
Link: {result['link']}
Thumbnail: {result['thumbnail']}
""")
```

Part of JSON response

```json
{
    "images_results": [
    {
      "position": 1,
      "thumbnail": "https://serpapi.com/searches/602e2750fdc2672ac69bb25c/images/2f2627191395d0e65f03259dbe2cf5bd9e3dcfa857b2c5e7ccf112bb03de4e4d.jpeg",
      "source": "en.wikipedia.org",
      "title": "Coffee - Wikipediaen.wikipedia.org",
      "link": "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee",
      "original": "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/45/A_small_cup_of_coffee.JPG"
    },
    {
      "position": 2,
      "thumbnail": "https://serpapi.com/searches/602e2750fdc2672ac69bb25c/images/2f2627191395d0e6349191ae0544016e04dfd1dd37e68655921d4107dec12b7e.jpeg",
      "source": "nbcnews.com",
      "title": "health benefits of coffeenbcnews.com",
      "link": "https://www.nbcnews.com/better/lifestyle/how-tap-health-benefits-coffee-ncna1096031",
      "original": "https://media3.s-nbcnews.com/j/newscms/2019_33/2203981/171026-better-coffee-boost-se-329p_67dfb6820f7d3898b5486975903c2e51.fit-1240w.jpg"
    }

    // Stripped...
}
```

Output

```
Images results

Title: Coffee - Wikipediaen.wikipedia.org
Source: en.wikipedia.org
Link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coffee
Thumbnail: https://serpapi.com/searches/602e2750fdc2672ac69bb25c/images/2f2627191395d0e65f03259dbe2cf5bd9e3dcfa857b2c5e7ccf112bb03de4e4d.jpeg


Title: health benefits of coffeenbcnews.com
Source: nbcnews.com
Link: https://www.nbcnews.com/better/lifestyle/how-tap-health-benefits-coffee-ncna1096031
Thumbnail: https://serpapi.com/searches/602e2750fdc2672ac69bb25c/images/2f2627191395d0e6349191ae0544016e04dfd1dd37e68655921d4107dec12b7e.jpeg

Stripped...
```

**Disclosure: I work at SerpApi.**